# What does "exercise" mean here?

Tags: meaning

REPORTING on big international summits is often an exercise in drudgery.
what does exercise mean here?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Please include the research you have already done and indicate what isn't clear in the information you found.  The way it has been posted, your question is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: What is an "exercise" in a math class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exercise here means an operation, activity or action.  There are a couple related phrases "Exercise in X" such as:

Exercise in futility - The activity is likely to fail.

Exercise in drudgery - The activity will be dull, boring, etc.